# Kerberos: Login failure for <user> from keytab file javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain p assword from user

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, hadoop, kerberos

I have a java program that uses a kerberos keytab file to securely log in to my hadoop server. I have used the below code to configure everything and it works perfectly fine in Eclipse IDE, but when I create an executable jar out of it, via Maven, and run on command line, it doesn't work. I see that it is able to read the keytab file but not able to retreive the password for the user id specified, thus the error. Any advise?

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
URL file = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file.keytab");
UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab("xyzUser", file.getPath());
```

My keytab file is saved in the root folder and I have added it to my pom.xml as a resource tag. Below is the command I am testing my jar file with:

```
java -jar myjar-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Comment: Is that the *only* error message you get -- e.g. nothing about "native libs" or "AES support"? Do you use the same, exact JDK? And did you enable the debugging trace as explained in https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html ?

Comment: check active keytab by using `klist` see if you find something interesting

Comment: yes that is the only message I see. java.io.IOException: Login failure for a_rfda1_nd from keytab file:/I:/workspace/POC/target/POC-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/user.keytab: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain p
assword from user

I see its pointing to the correct keytab file in my jar but not able to detect the encrypted password from it. I used version 1.8 in eclipse for JDK and run my jar with C:\FAST\JDK64\1.8.0.102\bin\java.exe command before -jar. let me try the debugging trace.

Comment: Tried the debugging and this is what I get, its the same principal key its looking for as defined in my keytab.
`Java config name: krb5.conf
>>> KdcAccessibility: reset
>>> KdcAccessibility: reset
Looking for keys for: user@DOMAIN.COM`

Comment: I did the klist on my keytab and I see 8 differently encrypted profiles, all with the same principal name. That should be fine I believe as the java program could pick any of the 8, unless there is a specific encryption I need to state? When I do klist after running the keytab I get a service principal that is different from my keytab principal.

Comment: `klist -e -k <keytab>` will show the actual encryption used on each entry. Kerberos tries each encryption allowed in its configuration, in that order. Also, if you have multiple KVNO, only the last one is used (with a 2nd try on the previous one, just in case the keytab has been updated before the actual password change)

Comment: So it seems the error is something different. I am bundling my .keytab file in the Jar i create and in my code, i give it the resource path. it seems that when jar get created, the bundled files are treated as streams, not files. The UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab API takes in the keytab file path and not the content of the file. 

I'm saying because when i hardcoded the path, it run perfectly fine on cmd line. Eclipse is very different in this case.

Comment: Did you fixed the error?

Comment: @FahadSheikh I am facing the same issue, I am able to run it in my local when the keytab is in local but facing issues when running it from JAR as it only accepts path and not streams, how did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

make sure the keytab file is in the current directory, other than classpath.